# Finding electric field of a line charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields

I have a bit of an issue setting up the integral for finding an electric field of a particular scenario. The scenario is that a line charge of length R is a distance R from the left side of the origin. Furthermore, the line charge starts below the x-axis so that only the top end touches the x-axis.

So I know that $dq=\lambda dysin\theta$.

Then $dE=k\frac{dq}{\sqrt{r^2}}=k\lambda \frac{ dy sin\theta}{\sqrt{y^2+R^2}}$.
Now since $sin\theta=\frac{R}{\sqrt{y^2+R^2}}$, $dE=k\lambda \frac{Rdy}{\sqrt{(y^2+R^2)^3}}$.
Then I would integrate from $-R$ to $0$.

Is that the correct set up? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a diagram?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are several mistakes in your derivation, although you miraculously end up with the right expression.

The term $\sin \theta$ comes from taking the horizontal (X) component of the electric field - not from the expression you used for $dq$. The diagram I envisage for your problem is this:

[image]

So I would say that

$$dq = \lambda dy$$
and then
$$dE = k\frac{dq}{r^2}$$
(no square root)

Now for the horizontal component, we need to take account of the factor $\frac{x}{r}$, making the final expression

$$dE = k\frac{\lambda\ dy}{r^2}\frac{x}{r}\\
= k\frac{\lambda\cdot x\cdot dy}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}$$

Now we can put $x=R$ and integrate from $-R$ to $0$:

$$E = \int_{-R}^{0}k\frac{\lambda R dy}{(R^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$